# How to obtain permission business_management in the Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

When updating the Facebook API from version 16.0 to version 18.0, I encountered the issue of the Data object coming empty at the '/me/accounts' endpoint when trying to retrieve the pages linked to the user's profile. Upon investigation, I found out that the advanced permission 'business_management' is required to obtain information about these pages.
My problem lies in requesting this permission for my application. Despite multiple attempts, it continues to be rejected, and I receive the following feedback:
-> App rejected - Unable to approve permission request
-> App rejected - Unable to determine use case details

I would like to know what I need to submit for this permission request to be approved.

I have already tried the following use cases:

-> We require the 'business_management' permission for our users to link their Facebook page associated with their Facebook profile and to gain access to all their pages. This includes pages linked through businesses, allowing users to effectively manage them.

-> We need the 'business_management' permission for our users to link their Facebook page that is associated with their Facebook profile and also pages that are linked through businesses, enabling them to manage them.

-> We need the business_management permission for our users to link the Facebook page that is associated with their Facebook profile, so they can manage their ads.

-> We need this permission because, after the update to API version 17.0, the "/me/accounts" endpoint added this permission to retrieve user account information. We require it to link the user's page and display posts, messages and other contents to the user.

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. Did you find a solution?